# While pero que vaya de 10 a 0

Tags: javascript

Pues quiero hacer un while que vaya de 10 a 0 en lugar de 0 hacia 10, es decir, que empieze en 10 y acabe en el 1, se que con el for es mas facil pero yo quiero hacerlo con  el while. mi codigo hasta ahora.

```
var count = 1;
                while (count<=10) {
                   document.write("Current Count : " + count + "<br />");
                   count++;
Current Count : 1
Current Count : 2
Current Count : 3
Current Count : 4
Current Count : 5
Current Count : 6
Current Count : 7
Current Count : 8
Current Count : 9
Current Count : 10
```

Eso es lo que me imprime pero yo quiero que me lo imprima empezando por el 10.

Comment: otra forma en tu mismo ejemplo ´document.write("Current Count : " + (11 - count) + "<br />");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var count = 10;

while(count>=0)
{
   //imprimo
   count--;
}
```

Lo que se hace es un ciclo decreciente y se va restando de 1 en 1 mientras count sea >= 0

Comment: Joder es asi, nose como lo he puesto antes que ha dado bucle infinito y se me ha ido a la mierda, gracias

Answer (score 0):

- Tu variable `count` ahora debe valer 10, pues ahora este es el límite a partir del cual comenzaremos la op. que afectará el valor que tiene asignado
- La condición que ahora evaluarás es : `count>=1`
- Dentro del ciclo en lugar del incremento harás un decremento con: [`variable--`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Decrement)

De tal forma que le indicamos a `count` le restarás uno por cada iteración mientras dicha variable sea mayor o igual a 1

```js
    let count = 10;
    
    while (count>=1) {
      console.log(`Current value: ${count}`);
      count--;
    }
```

Comment: para que sirve el console.log?

Comment: Imprimir en consola, solo cámbialo por la sentencia que ya tienes y todo ok @Jose

Answer (score 0):

```js
var count = 10;
while (count>=1) {document.write("Current Count : " + count + "<br />");
                   count--;}
```